# Update positions (properties)

Tags: javascript

I'm having some problems with Javascript. I'm trying to move a div while some img are moving and bouncing against the screen and the div itself. My problem is that my div is moving but my img are bouncing against the initial position of the div, not the new positions the div is getting when it is moving. It's like if the bounce position wasn't updating as the div moves. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate the modal from the rendering.  By that, I mean create 3 objects one for the screen, on for your div and on for the image.  This is your modal.  In the screen object, you put information that will help you render the objects (stuff like height and width, etc...).  In the objects for you div and image, you put the top and left to know where they are in the modal.  When you check where is an object from one another, you look for the values in those objects.  And at regular intervals, you render the modal to the web page.

There still alot of global variables and global functions that you could put in objects.  This will simplify the code and your understanding of what is going on.

Most of all you should centralize an algorithm that given an array of (top,left,heigth,width) can verify if any objects overlap with one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with something like that, your code will be shorter and easier to understand because there is less code.

```
function getNextPossition (position, vector) {
  return {"x": position.x + vector.deltaX, "y": position.y + vector.deltaY};
}

function Rectangle (size, position) {
  this.positionTopLeft = {"x": position.x, "y": position.y};
  this.positionBottomRight = {"x": position.x + size.width - 1, "y":     position.y + size.heigth - 1};
  this.size = {"width": size.width, "heigth": size.heigth};

  this.union = function (rectangle) {
    var newPositionTopLeft = {"x": (rectangle.positionTopLeft.x < this.positionTopLeft.x ? rectangle.positionTopLeft.x :this.positionTopLeft.x ), "y": (rectangle.positionTopLeft.y < this.positionTopLeft.y ? rectangle.positionTopLeft.y :this.positionTopLeft.y )};
    var newPositionBottomRight = {"x": (rectangle.positionBottomRight.x > this.positionBottomRight.x ? rectangle.positionBottomRight.x :this.positionBottomRight.x ), "y": (rectangle.positionBottomRight.y > this.positionBottomRight.y ? rectangle.positionBottomRight.y :this.positionBottomRight.y )};
    var newSize = {"width": newPositionBottomRight.x - newPositionTopLeft.x + 1, "heigth": newPositionBottomRight.y - newPositionTopLeft.y + 1};
    return new Rectangle(newSize, newPositionTopLeft);
  };

  this.doesOverlap = function (rectangle) {
    return !(rectangle.positionBottomRight.x < this.positionTopLeft.x
             || this.positionBottomRight.x < rectangle.positionTopLeft.x
             || rectangle.positionBottomRight.y < this.positionTopLeft.y
             || this.positionBottomRight.y < rectangle.positionTopLeft.y);
  }
}

var list_obj = [];
function Obj (rectangle, vector0) {
  this.id = list_obj.length; list_obj.push(this);

  this.rect = new Rectangle(rectangle.size, rectangle.positionTopLeft);
  this.vertor = {"deltaX": vector0.deltaX, "deltaX": vector0.deltaX};

  this.getNextPossition = function() {
    var newPositionTopLeft = getNextPossition(this.rect.positionTopLeft, this.vertor);
    var newSize = {"width": this.size.width, "heigth": this.size.heigth};
    return new Rectangle(newSize, newPositionTopLeft);
  };

  this.getMovementBoundry = function(nextRect) {
    var newPositionTopLeft = getNextPossition(this.rect.positionTopLeft, this.vertor);
    var newSize = {"width": this.size.width, "heigth": this.size.heigth};
    return this.rect.union(this.getNextPossition());
  };

  this.move = function () {
    var overlap = [];
    var mov_boundry = list_obj.map(function (e,i) {return e.getMovementBoundry(e.getNextPossition());});
    for (var i = mov_boundry.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      if (list_obj[i].id !== this.id) {
        if (mov_boundry[this.id].rect.doesOverlap(mov_boundry[i].rect)) {
          overlap.push(list_obj[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    if (overlap.length > 0) {
      //change direction
      // TODO
      return;
    }
    this.rect = this.getNextPossition();
  }
}
```